# Get coordinates of mouse pointer over PDF in Python?

Tags: python, pdf, tkinter, coordinates

I have a need to get the x/y coordinates from a PDF using the mouse pointer. I need to show a PDF to the user, then collect the x/y coords of the mouse pointer when they click the mouse button.

So if [this file](https://www.adobe.com/support/products/enterprise/knowledgecenter/media/c4611_sample_explain.pdf) was displayed, the user could position the mouse over the top-left corner of the "Accelio" logo and clicked the mouse button, the code would return something like "50, 100", representing the X and Y of the mouse pointer location from the top-left (0,0) of the document.

The coordinates need to be the coordinates of the PDF, not the screen. I need to be able to use the coordinates that come in to then write some text or add an image to that PDF using PyMuPDF in some other code (which I already have working).

Is there a way to do that in TKinter or something else?

Thanks!

Comment: You're probably going to have to use some third-party pdf reading module to display the file, and it may contain utility functions that do what you need.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?